# Non installable application and new regulations for publishing on google apps marketplace

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I’m new with the marketplace and I’m developing an application to replace google's login with my app, which uses strong authentication.

To use it you don’t need to install anything, it’s only a matter of configuration of your google app. When you try to access mail.google.com/a/yourdomain.com it will redirect to our application where the validation process occurs, and after validating it will return to google web site.

Same happens with logout and password change, you will be redirected to my app.
When a user needs to change the account password, we use google admin api to change it, of course, it requieres a previous authorization from a domain user with administration privileges.

Question is, how to publish an application like this on the market place?, I don’t see how to do it according to the new regulations from november 19th, for example, the application type and the fact that it should be an installable listing.

Someone who can give me a hint or example.

Thanks in advance.

Fernando.

**--- EDITED --- to answer to Koma**

The thing is, we already have the application, what we're doing now is to do some changes to make it ready to use it with google apps.

There’s an option in the security section called “set up single sign-on (SSO)” where you configure 3 URL’s for:
Sign-in page URL (URL for signing in to your system and Google Apps)
Sign-out page URL (URL to redirect users to when they sign out)
Change password URL (URL to let users change their password in your system; when defined here, this URL is shown even when Single Sign-on is not enabled)

When you a user needs to change your account’s password you will be redirected to our application (because google have delegated that responsibility to Us). There, through OAUTH and Google Admin API, we will change the password for your google user.

We want to be listed in google’s marketplace as a solution for strong authentication delegating that functionality to our application, but we don’t see how because the user that will use our solution doesn’t need to install anything, and according to what I understand we are forced to upload something to be listed

Does that make sense to you?

Comment: It's never gonna work to put something in the market that does not authenticate via Google. That's more or less the concept of this market.

Answer (score 0):

From what I read, you want to replace authentication with your own. That's not feasible with a market place app.

You need to implement a SAML identity provider

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sso/saml_reference_implementation

Comment: I changed the original question to give you more information. Thanks

Comment: @user3111037 google apps market place apps before 19th nov requred integration with Google's openId to authenticate. Since 19th of november, a apps market place is required to use OAUTH2 with scopes user.info and user.profile; Any app with different authentication cannot be published in the apps market place.